# Как удостовериться в корректности работы нейронной сети?

Tags: python, keras

Обучил классифицирующую нейронную сеть. Результат на тестовых данных равен 99 процентам. Соотношение тестовых и тренировочных данных 0.33 к 0.67. Размер датасета 11 тысяч. Классификация в данном случае бинарная. А нейронная сеть имеет всего один скрытый слой.

Проверял признаки на наличие доминирующих, таких не было обнаружено. confusion matrix тоже ничего не показала.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, что можно прочитать по данной теме или на что еще можно обратить внимание.